# "AndroidSdkData.getSdkData must not be null" error after installing Android Studio 3.2

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I uninstalled Android Studio 2.3 and installed 3.2 but after installation when I opened Android Studio, I'm getting this error:

> Gradle sync failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'sdk' of org/jetbrains/android/sdk/AndroidSdkData.getSdkData must not be null

Also in Device File Explorer, I'm getting the error:

> Error initializing ADB: Android Debug Bridge not found.

Comment: The device file explorer error
_Error initializing ADB: Android Debug Bridge not found_
 is in all likelihood  symptomatic of your Gradle sync error and could be removed from the question.

Comment: Simply **rebuilding** solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

If you get the error "Please select Android SDK" you can try the following:

1. Open Android Studio -> File -> Project Structure
2. Choose your module (e.g., app)
3. Check that you have chosen the build tools version and correct it if not.